# Xcode Asset Catalog issues

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, asset-catalog

I just started using Asset Catalogs in Xcode, so had few questions about better organization of catalog.

I have over 100 button images, each image has 5 versions(@1x, @2x, @3x, @1x iPad, @2x iPad).

1. One way is to create 100 image sets in the catalog file. However, that would be too clumsy. Is it possible to group related image sets together?
2. Is there a better way of importing 500 images than manual drag and drop?

Answer (score 2):

Name your image files using the `@x~device` format, such as:

```
btn1@1x~iphone.png
btn1@2x~iphone.png
btn1@3x~iphone.png
btn1@1x~ipad.png
btn1@2x~ipad.png
```

You can then add them as individual files in your project, putting them in groups / folders as desired:

[image]

Now, you can set a button (or image view, etc) image via code:

```
if let img = UIImage(named: "btn1") {
    button1.image = img
}
```

and iOS / UIKit will automatically use the correct image for the device.

Or, you can set the image in Storyboard / IB. Note that when you select the image from the drop-down list in Attributes Inspector pane, it will show as:

```
btn1.png
```

however, at run-time -- or, if you use Preview or `View as:` to change the device in Xcode -- the correct image will be used.

Give it a try with these images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

The `@1x` images are `128 x 128`, the `@2x` images are `256 x 256` and the `@3x` image is `384 x 384`.

**Note:** You *can* also use Asset Catalog without having to drag the files one-by-one. If you have the set of 5 files names as above, open an Asset Catalog in Xcode and drag-and-drop all 5 files into the Catalog. Xcode will automatically configure them:

[image]

Comment: hmm, but no way to group buttons in the same catalog.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Lets say I have a group of buttons that sit in the top panel. Is there a way to create a catalog "Top Panel" and have 5-6 image sets in it (visible in the same screen, not separate screen for each image).

Comment: Yes, you can create multiple asset catalog. Probably worth your time to do a little learning about them. Google search for `xcode asset catalogs`

Comment: Ah you wanna create a different catalog for each group, that's nice but I wanted grouping in the same catalog.